# Finding bounds of integration non-graphically

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

I have this curve given in polar form:

$$
\rho=4\sin2\phi
$$

I'm trying to find the integration bounds of the area it creates, like this:

$$
t = 2\phi \\
t \in [0 + 2k\pi, \pi+2k\pi], k\in Z \\
0+2k\pi \le t \le\pi+2k\pi \\
0+2k\pi \le 2\phi \le\pi+2k\pi \\
k\pi \le \phi \le \frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi \\
0 \le \phi \le \frac{\pi}{2} \vee \pi \le \phi \le \frac{3\pi}{2}\\
$$

The base period of sin function is $2\pi$ and $\sin \ge 0$ only at $\phi \in [0 + 2k\pi, \pi+2k\pi]$, which means that $4\sin2\phi \ge 0$ when $\phi \in [k\pi, \frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi]$. So that's why I've written the last line as my integration bounds, but now I know that those are not all of them. Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to consider all $k,$ because you want area of a single petal of the rose and it is possible to consider symmetry for congruent areas. Radius $\rho $ vanishes when $ \sin 2 \phi=0\rightarrow 2\phi= 0, \pi. $ This will be clear while finding tangents when $\rho=0$

*Polar angles $\theta$ at origin set as limits of tangential positions :*

$$\rho= a \sin 2 \theta\tag1$$

Angles $(\psi,\theta)$  are expressed by relations
$$ \rho'= \cos \psi, \theta'= \dfrac{\sin \psi }{\rho} \tag2$$

Differentiating on arc length using above differential relations

$$  \cos \psi = \rho'= 2a \cos 2 \theta  \cdot \theta' \tag3$$

Simplify

$$\tan \psi = \dfrac12 \tan  2 \theta \tag4 $$

Tangent at origin occurs in this case at

$$  (\psi= 0,\; \phi=0,\; \rho=0 \;;) \tag5 $$

$$ 2 \theta = \tan ^{-1} 0= 0, \pi \tag6$$

So tangency at origin occurs at:

$$ \theta= (0,\pi/2) \tag7$$

Total Area

$=8\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac12 \rho^2 d\phi $ Plug in $\rho $ to evaluate Area further.

To check slope of tangent at any point $\gamma= \theta+\psi$

Comment: You know it's a rose because you've either drawn it or just know it by heart. What I'm after is an algebraic or analytical way (so a non-graphical one) of uncovering integration bounds for a figure created by a curve in polar coords. Besides, isn't it $from 0 to \frac{\pi}{2}$ ?

Comment: OK, I see what you mean: Your question is: Show by means of the tangent  at origin what the local slopes are. Right?  Possible to show that local slopes to x-axis are $(0,\pi/ 2)$ at origin using differential geometrical relations.

Comment: @ Marek M.  So as an exercise to further apply this procedure suggest you find tangent limits in   $ \rho=  \sin 2t + \cos t.$